# RegisterClassObjects with “REGCLS_SINGLEUSE” is not launching multiple process (out-proc server) for each CoCreateInstanceEx call

Tags: c++, com, atl, dcom

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and Win7 64 bit
I want to start a new process (out-proc server) for each client request (CoCreateInstanceEx). The steps I have followed to achieve are

Override PreMessageLoop.
In the PreMessageLoop function I am registering my class object as “REGCLS_SINGLEUSE”.
RegisterClassObjects(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER, REGCLS_SINGLEUSE);

So for each CoCreateInstanceEx call a new server process should start. But it’s creating only one exe for the following code snippet.

```
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
// COSERVERINFO and MULTI_QI creation and initialization is done here.
hr = ::CoCreateInstanceEx(__uuidof(MyClass), NULL, CLSCTX_SERVER, &oServerInfo, 1, multi_qi);
_ASSERTE( SUCCEEDED(hr) );
}
```